# Access Item in PFObject in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, parse-platform

I have an array of `PFObjects`. How can I access the value of a particular key. For example, I would like to access `"Name"` of each restaurant.

I was thinking something like:
`restaurantArray["Name"]`, but I need to specify the array index?

```
[<Restaurant: 0x7feb9252cfc0, objectId: LA74J92QDA, localId: (null)> {
    Name = "Restaurant 1";        
    City = "New York";
    Closed = 1;
    Country = "United States";
    FoodType = Japanese;
}, <Restaurant: 0x7feb926afa00, objectId: 0aKFrpKN46, localId: (null)> {
    Name = "Restaurant 2";        
    City = "San Francisco";
    Closed = 1;
    Country = "United States";
    FoodType = Italian;
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to specify the array index for the restaurant you want to get the name for, e.g. `restaurantArray[0].objectForKey("Name")`

If you want to extract all the names for all the restaurants to a separate array, you could do something like this

```
let namesArray = restaurantsArray.map { $0.objectForKey("Name") }
```

Comment: thanks for the response. what does `restaurantsArray.map` do? I'm not familiar with `map` and couldn't find doc on it.

Comment: @Rachel It runs the closure (the code inside {}) over each element ($0) of the restaurantsArray. It's like a foreach loop. Apple's documentation on this is poor. More info at http://practicalswift.com/2014/06/14/the-swift-standard-library-list-of-built-in-functions/